# Distinguish between registers in microprocessor 8086/8088 and microprocessor in computers (ex: intel i7 6820hq)

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, x86-16, cpu-registers

Can someone help to distinguish the registers components and functions for 8086/8088 and for the chip we usually use (for my case is intel i7 6820hq).

I have read materials from geek 2 geeks, intel 8086/8088 reference books and intel datasheet but it is too tricky to find out the main difference between those 2 kinds

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/CPU_Registers_x86-64 shows 64-bit mode registers that exist.  8086 was missing FS and GS, and integer regs only up to 16-bit size, and not r8..r15 (or DIL/SIL/BPL/SPL which require REX prefixes to access).  Presumably missing all the debug and control regs, and of course no GDTR/LDTR.  https://stevemorse.org/8086/ (the 8086 primer) is a good intro to the ISA with only 8086 features, written by the guy who architected it, now free on his web site.

Comment: What kind of differences do you want to know? This question is like "Can someone please explain to me the difference between the Ford Model T and the Mach E?" There's multiple generations of differences in both quantity (cache/register/memory size/speed) and quality (most features of modern cpus didn't exist back then).

Comment: Also, are you only asking about architectural state, or also implementation? (Especially register renaming, see https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/5/ for info on the PRF in Sandybridge-family)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your help, I have found the desired answers to this question.